# python IMAP4-SSL ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=932, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET6,

Tags: python, imap

I am using python `IMAP4_SSL` to read emails as below, but at the end, I get a warning. How do I get rid of it?

I do not want to silence the warning because I want to know why it is giving me an SSL Socket warning. Am I forgetting to close a socket and if so, how do I close it?

```
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    username = self.Dict["emailUsername"]
    password = self.Dict["emailPassword"]
    print(username, password)
    mail.login(username, password)
    mail.list()
    mail.select("inbox")
     result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
    and so on I do my thing
```

How can I close the SSL Socket so I don't get that warning?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I had not closed the mail I should have done this at the end

```
    mail.close()
    mail.logout()
```